# How To Work Out Percentage From Same Table With Different Constraints

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns, where Type_ID is a type of vehicle, eg cars, bicycles and so on.

A few rows of data would look something like this:

```
ID  Traffic  Type_ID  Year
 1     5000        1  2000
 2       15        2  2000
 3     2100        3  2000
```

What I'm trying to do is to work out the percentage of one specific type against the total for that year (there are multiple years in the source table).

So, if I select on a particular value of `Type_ID`, I need results that resemble:

```
2000   0.4%
2001   0.61%
2002   0.73%
```

I've tried joins, unions, subqueries and all sorts - this has got me stumped!  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what you've tried, what they returned (if anything) and your expected output for the queries?

Comment: @BrettBlade, do you want the percentage for a year (as you seem to say), or do you want the percentage per type against the year's total (as you say `the % of one specific type against the total for that year`).

Comment: David, yes, to expand my original comment: the % of one specific type against the total (of all types) for each year.

Comment: @BrettBlade, OK, please see my answer below.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I've not got anything substantial to show my efforts because I've either had multiple errors or the wrong results returned.  There is data for numerous years, and as an example, I need to know the % of cars compared to all vehicles (cars, bikes, buses - the type_ids) for each year.

Comment: Can you at least edit your expected results to show what you expect for 2000 from your sample data - are you expecting the type_id as a column in the results, as you seem to want the percentage per type? Or are you querying one type at a time?

Comment: @Alex, I only need the figures for one type (and only ever one type), but the total obviously needs to take into account all types.  Type_id doesn't need to be included in the results, just year and the calculated percentage (the query will become a chart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an analytic `sum()` to get the total for the year as a pseudocolumn, and use that to calculate the percentage for each row:

```
select id, traffic, type_id, year,
  round(100 * traffic / sum(traffic) over (partition by year), 2) as pct
from t42
order by id;

        ID    TRAFFIC    TYPE_ID       YEAR        PCT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       5000          1       2000      70.27 
         2         15          2       2000        .21 
         3       2100          3       2000      29.52
```

I've rounded the percentage to two decimal places but that's optional.

If you want the percentage of the total traffic per type, you can either use an analytic sum for that too, which requires a `distinct` which makes it a bit messy:

```
select distinct type_id, year,
  round(100 * sum(traffic) over (partition by type_id, year)
    / sum(traffic) over (partition by year), 2) as pct
from t42
order by type_id;
```

Or use a subquery that finds the total for each type and year:

```
select type_id, year,
  round(100 * traffic / sum(traffic) over (partition by year), 2) as pct
from (
  select type_id, year, sum(traffic) as traffic
  from t42
  group by type_id, year
)
order by type_id, year;
```

With your very limited sample data all three queries get the same result, but with more than one ID per type/year you'll just see the totals from either of these two.

If you only want the result for a single type, you can use either of those as a further subquery, with a filter for type_id, e.g.

```
select year, pct
from (
  select type_id, year,
    round(100 * traffic / sum(traffic) over (partition by year), 2) as pct
  from (
    select type_id, year, sum(traffic) as traffic
    from t42
    group by type_id, year
  )
)
where type_id = 1
order by year;

      YEAR        PCT
---------- ----------
      2000      70.27
```

Again you've only given one year of sample data, but this will show one row per year with more data.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want something like follows:

```
SELECT year, type_pct FROM (
    SELECT year, type_id, traffic/SUM(traffic) OVER ( PARTITION BY year ) AS type_pct
      FROM mytable
 )
 WHERE type_id = 1 -- or 2 or 3 etc.
```

Comment: David, would this give the % against the total for all the years? Or the % for that one year against the total of all types?

Comment: It would give the % for one type against the total for all types for each year